# How to create a list of hyperlinks to files stored locally?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm trying to automate the creation of a list of hyperlinks to picture files. My worksheet has the filenames listed in column A and I want the hyperlinks to those files (saved in the parent folder of the worksheet) to columm B. I am a beginner to VBA, but thougth this should be fairly simple, however I was unable to find a way to do this.

I tried using the Macro Recorder and got this:

```
    Sub Hyperlink()
'
' Hyperlink Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+l
'
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ACTIVITY '#]]").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "file(a)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ACTIVITY '#]]").Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        "..\file(a).JPG", TextToDisplay:="..\file(a).JPG"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("Table1[[#Headers],[ACTIVITY '#]]").Select
End Sub
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the cells and create the hyperlinks and just reference the column that holds the data.

```
Sub CreateJpgHyperLinks()
Dim iRow, iCol As Integer 'row and column counters

iRow = 1 'change to 2 if there are headers
iCol = 1 'Column A
    'this assumes there is data in all cells in column A
    Do While ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value <> ""
        'set the link in column B and point it to the info in column A
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol + 1), Address:=ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value, _
        TextToDisplay:=ActiveSheet.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
        'move to the next row
        iRow = iRow + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

To find the folder you can use the method below

```
'get path to current workbook
workbookPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
'find the last slash in the workbook path
iLastFolderSlash = InStrRev(workbookPath, "\")
'create the folder location by removing the last folder from the path
jpgFolderPath = Left(workbookPath, iLastFolderSlash)
```

Comment: Just tried this solution. Two things that I'd like to tweek.

1) I'd like to add ".JPG" to the hyperlink and display name.
2) The hyperlink needs to link to the folder one above in the tree (e.g. \\photos\photo spreadsheet\spreadsheet.xls ==> hyperlink to photos)

I hope this is clear. Thank you again for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try and add those features yourself? I can do it for you but then you learn nothing.  Give it a try and post back with what you have if you run into issues.

Comment: So far I figured out how to add the ".jpg" to the display name. I'm still trying to figure out how to reference a different folder containing the pictures. I can't seem to find this info. I've looked through a number of online tutorials as well as the MS Office Development Center online resource. Can't find what I'm looking for yet.

Comment: @user2309060 I have updated the answer to show you how to get the path of the workbook and then get the folder above it.  As always dont forget to mark as answered if it resolves your issue.

Comment: I think I've got it. I'm going to play with it a bit and make sure it does what I need it to do. Thanks for your help.